Include data from root folder with setuptools
I have the following folder structure:
- myproject/
--- __init__.py
--- stuff.py
- other-folder/
--- more-stuff.txt
pyproject.toml
MANIFEST.in
file.txt

How can I include the file.txt and the other-folder within the wheel? (Basically, I want to mimick the behaviour of pip install -e ... without the -e flag.)
I tried this config:
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["myproject"] # or myproject*

When installing, myproject becomes the root folder though. The other-folder and the file.txt are missing. Both are included in MANIFEST.in.

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html -- other-folder should be an import package. Better make it a subpackage of myproject.

How are you trying to locate your data files? Is it using importlib.resources? You might want to also consider switching to src layout which helps prevent accidentally accessing data files not available in the packaged module.
